# GreaseMonkey: Redirect immediately to special web page

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, greasemonkey

I know my way around in different programming languages, but I'm actually new to javascript and GreaseMonkey. After some searching (here and on the net), I could not find an answer to the following problem:

I want to have a local javascript that works on Zeit Online and forwards me automatically to the complete article view (that is not divided into several subpages).

Example:
When I call
www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2015-02/griechenland-euro-schaeuble-varoufakis

I want to be redirected immediately to 
www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2015-02/griechenland-euro-schaeuble-varoufakis/komplettansicht
(note the /komplettansicht at the end).

Exemption:
On www.zeit.de/index I want to change nothing. One could say that extending the URL requires that the webpage URL consists of www.zeit.de and a subdirectory.

How do I do that in javascript/GreaseMonkey?

**update**:

```
 var regex = /^(https?:\/\/.+\.zeit\.de\/.+\/.+)$/i;
```

and

```
.replace(regex, "$1/komplettansicht");
```

should surface in the code. But how do I replace the URL and call it?

Comment: The regex (https?:\/\/.+\.zeit\.de\/.+\/.+) subst by $1/komplettansicht would work...

Comment: I'd rather suggest using [redirector addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/redirector/) instead of custom script.. It supports some basic level of regex with back-reference..

Comment: thanks, anishsane, that works. Here is my redirector pattern: "includePattern": "http://(.+).zeit.de/(.+)/(.+)", "excludePattern": ".+/komplettansicht",  "redirectUrl": "http://$1.zeit.de/$2/$3/komplettansicht",

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the javascript console first:

`window.location = window.location.href + "/komplettansicht";`

maybe need to wrap this line of code in an `if` statement that checks that you aren't on the homepage of zeit.de any longer, and that the page does not end with "komplettansicht" (it would redirect forever to `komplettansicht/komplettansicht/komplettansicht`...)

But then a dialog box with a warning may open asking if you really want to leave the page. Not sure about that.

If it doesn't work, replace `window.` with `unsafeWindow.` (Greasemonkey wraps the raw window object with a new object of this name)

Comment: thanks for the hint on infinite redirecting. I had that to consider using the redirector addon, as described in the solution above